# What is the meaning of this attribute in .NET

Tags: .net, attributes

What is the meaning of this attribute?

```
<System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethod(ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, True)> _
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This explains it perfectly](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=390)

Answer (score 1):

The [DataObjectAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectattribute.aspx) "identifies a type as an object suitable for binding to an ObjectDataSource object."

The [DataObjectMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataobjectmethodattribute.aspx) classifies the methods of a class used as an ObjectDataSource with regard to the type of data method is supported (select, update, insert, delete) and whether it is the default.  The particular attribute referenced marks the method as the default selection method for the class.